# NODE JS soap request with call TLS certificate (JKS)

Tags: node.js, ssl, soap, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

currently i am working on my services to send TLS certificates with each soap services, i have created the client and server side which accepts soap request with certificate(JKS) in java... But i am not able to find any examples that client side nodejs to send soap request with JKS or PEM files.

Could you please help me on this, if you have any link where i can get information about nodejs example to send soap request to server with TLS certificates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the self-signed certificate pinning. I only find out a way to do that one by `https` module. For example below:

```js
const fs = require('fs'); 
const https = require('https'); 
const options = { 
    hostname: 'localhost', 
    port: 8080, 
    path: '/', 
    method: 'POST', 
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem') 
}; 
const req = https.request(options, function(res) { 
    res.on('data', function(data) { 
        process.stdout.write(data); 
    }); 
}); 
req.end();
```

`!Noted`: when you send to soap you have to check carefully the header and body like.
+ 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
+ 'soapaction': `actionName`,
+ 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',